# Jenkins won't use arguments after variable substitution

Tags: docker, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use a variable related to the SHA of a Gemfile. The problem is that when I use it in a sh command, the other arguments won't be interpreted.
So, for example:

```
docker build ${VAR} .
```

will result in an error stating that "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument, since the " ." of the command is not being interpreted.

Here is the code that tries to pull an image, builds it and publish it:

```
def GEMFILE_SHA = ""

pipeline {
.....
    stages {
        stage("Build Docker Image and Push to Artifactory - Snapshot Repository") {
            steps {
             container("docker") {
                script {
                    GEMFILE_SHA = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "sha256sum Gemfile | cut -d ' ' -f1 | head -n1", label: "Set Gemfile sha")
                }
                sh script: "docker login -u ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_CREDS_USR} -p ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_CREDS_PSW} ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL}", label: "Docker Login."
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'SUCCESS') {
                    sh script: "docker pull ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL}/${DOCKER_REPO}:${GEMFILE_SHA}", label: "Pull Cached Image."
                }
                sh script: "docker build  --network=host --no-cache -t ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL}/${DOCKER_REPO}:${GEMFILE_SHA} .", label: "Build Docker Image."
                sh script: "docker push ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL}/${DOCKER_REPO}:${GEMFILE_SHA}", label: "Push Docker Image."
              }
            }    
        }  
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two white spaces here `docker build  --network` between build and --network. Please remove them and try to rebuild

Comment: it didnt worked :(

Comment: using `docker build ... -f Dockerfile`